# Repaint() not calling paintComponent() Java

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm trying to remake Snake to improve my programming, Ive been reading about other people having the same problem for hours but none of them seem to be similar to my own code. Here is my relevant code:

```
package snake;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayGame extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private JFrame jfr;
    private JPanel jpn;

    PickupBall b = new PickupBall();
    Snake bob = new Snake();

    public PlayGame(){
        jfr = new JFrame("Snake");            
        jfr.setSize(640,640);
        jfr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jpn = new JPanel();
        jpn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        jfr.add(jpn);            
        jfr.setVisible(true);             
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){            
        while(true){                
            repaint();
        }
    }        

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){            
        super.paintComponent(g);            
        b.draw(g);
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        PlayGame p = new PlayGame();  
        Thread t = new Thread(p);

        t.start();           

    }


 }
```

Everything works, the while(true) loop is initiated, but nothing happens.

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class PickupBall {
//constructor
public PickupBall(){
    xPos = (int) (((Math.random()*31)+1)*20);
    yPos = (int) (((Math.random()*31)+1)*20);        
}
//constants
public final int balletjeSides = 20;

//variables
public int xPos;
public int yPos;
//methods
public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRoundRect(this.xPos, this.yPos, balletjeSides, balletjeSides, 5, 5);
}

}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your instance of `PlayGame` is never displayed in your code, so its painting is obviously not visible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `jfr.setContentPane(this);` within your `onstructor`, as what @Berger said, you actually have a `JPanel`, `PlayGame` instance here, but the `JFrame` you´re creating doesn´t use this `JPanel` instance, but instead simply adds an empty `JPanel`, called `jpn` in your code, to your `jfr` which doesn´t have any content.

The new `constructor` could look like this:

```
private JFrame jfr;
//private JPanel jpn;

PickupBall b = new PickupBall();
//Snake bob = new Snake();

public PlayGame() {
    jfr = new JFrame("Snake");
    jfr.setSize(640, 640);
    jfr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //jpn = new JPanel();
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //jfr.add(jpn);
    jfr.setContentPane(this);
    jfr.setVisible(true);
}
```

As you see, i commented out the `jpn` variable, as the actual `JPanel` you´d like to work with (my guess) is the `PlayGame` class itself, and not an `JPanel` defined within this class.

Comment: Oh wow, I cant believe my head did not connect the dots between "extends JPanel" and my class gaining the functionality of a JPanel. Thanks!